# SailsJS: Is it possible to populate a model's associations after creation without a second trip to the database?

Tags: sails.js

The model instance returned from `User.create()` does not include populated associations.  Is it possible to populate the returned instance from the create function without a second trip to the database?

I'd like to avoid:

```
User.create(userData).exec(function (err, user) {
  if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

  User.findById(user.id)
    .populate('tags').exec(function (err, populatedUser) {
       // Do stuff
    });
});
```